# Is it possible to use a default parameter within an expression before its defined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-value

I have a function that has a value that will always need to be converted. I was wondering if there was a way I could take the value and use some division before it hits the function body? Right now I'm doing the division in the body but always looking for a new and better way in doing things:

```
// Prices come in the the form of thousands (e.g. 24 => 2400) so division is necessary here
const formatPrice = (price = (price / 100), commaSeparated = true) => {
  if (commaSeparated) {
    return value.toLocaleString('en-GB', {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2
    });
  }

  return value;
}
```

With the above I'll get the error:

```
'price' was used before it was defined
```

Comment: The default value comes into play when there is no actual parameter passed. Given that, what is it that you want the expression to actually do?

Comment: I can't help but ask why you would want to do this? What would the benefit be over just doing it in the function?

Comment: @Pointy I guess I want to pre-format the value before it hits the body.

Comment: I agree with Nit; if "price" needs to be divided by 100 every time it's used in this function, let the division be part of the function.

Comment: Right, but that's not what the default argument mechanism is for. It's for providing a value when none is passed in an actual call to the function.

Comment: Right. My mistake. Another case of trying to be clever for my own good. I'll go ahead and remove this.

Comment: If you doesn't want it to be part of this function you can have 2 functions. One with formatting and another one expecting teh data like ``24`` instead of  ``2400``.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't really the best way to do things, one possible way would be to add an extra parameter and use its default value as the expression like so:

```js
const formatPrice = (price, commaSeparated = true, dividedPrice = price / 100) => {
}
```

This would work as expected as long as you don't call the function with 3 arguments. I would recommend that you simply just do the division inside the function though.